# Issues with Adobe AIR File access when file name has a semi-colon

Tags: macos, apache-flex, air

I have a piece of code in AIR that accesses a file on the hard drive.  This fails to work on a mac if the file name contains a semi-colon.  It throws an exception that it can't find the file.  If I rename the file and remove the semi-colon and point to it it works fine so the code is ok. The only problem is when the filename contains a semi-colon.  The exception occurs on the line where I request file.size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 

  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 

  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"

  creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

<fx:Script> <![CDATA[

import mx.events.FlexEvent;


protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void

{

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

var f:File = new File("file:///Users/foo/pix/test;1.JPG");

trace (" here" + f.size );

}


]]>

</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>

<!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->

</fx:Declarations>



</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: What is your question? If it can not be done, it can not be done. There is really no room for "hacks"

Comment: What I mean by above comment is, why not just stop using semicolons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use semi colons in filenames.

See this article from 2007

http://www.portfoliofaq.com/pfaq/FAQ00352.htm

> Deprecated filename characters (; and ,). (All OSs).